# Question on command to look at performance counters

Tags: powershell

Does anyone if the command(s) to look at performance counters via Powershell uses COM?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something more than, "yes" or "no"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a bit of spelunking with .NET Reflector is appears the Get-Counter command is using the [Performance Data Helper API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373078(v=VS.85).aspx) via pdh.dll which doesn't appear to be COM-based.  It appears to me like a C-style WINAPI.